# How to convert a React Typescript project to Javascript ES5

Tags: typescript, babeljs, create-react-app, react-typescript

I have a react typescript project. And I need to convert the source code (NOT THE BUILD) to ES3 or ES5 Js. Because I want to use this code as a component in another react app.

Can you please suggest which preset and plugins to use to do the job?

I have tried the combination of the following babel presets and plugins

```
 "presets": [
  "@babel/preset-env",
  "@babel/preset-react",
  "@babel/preset-typescript",
  "@babel/preset-flow"
],
"plugins": [
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript"
],
```

Earlier I my project was plain reactJs without typescript and at that time I was able to transpile using following combination.

```
 "presets": [
  "@babel/preset-react"
],
"plugins": [
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
],
```

Kindly provide a solution to convert ReactJs + Typescript source code to es3/es5 js.

Answer (score 2):

> And I need to convert the source code (NOT THE BUILD) to ES3 or ES5 Js

If you want to *Upgrade* the src to TS you are best to do it by hand gradually. That said ES3 is valid TypeScript!.  To enable TypeScript to use `.js` files you can enable the `allowjs` compiler option in tsconfig.json.
Official docs on `allowJs` can be found here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs

If you want to compile TS to JavaScript then `"@babel/preset-typescript",` is exactly what you need. For finer control you can use options based on target : https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targets

Comment: sir I tried using "@babel/preset-typescript". but it is not converting '.ts' files to '.js ' files. Along with this preset I am also using "@babel/preset-react" in preset and  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining" in plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The only turnaround that I'm currently using is to just rename App.tsx to App.js and add your own Javascript code to App.js